# Объединение нескольких подзапросов

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет! Есть два запроса, которые нужно объединить, чтобы на выходе получился следующий результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1 запрос

```
with 
oems as (
select unnest(array['54830D7000']) oem
)
select k.pv, sum(count) as istcohnik1 from (
select p.value->>'raw' as pv, count(distinct contractor_code)
from stat.phrase p
  join oems o on o.oem=p.value->>'raw' 
  join stat.event_request_stat rq on rq.phrase_uid=p.uid and lower(rq.period) between '9999-99-99' and '9999-99-99' and rq.period_type='M'
  where p.value->>'raw' is not null and contractor_code is not null and src in ('источник1')
group by p.value->>'raw') as K
group by k.pv
```

2 запрос:

```
select t.pv, sum(count) as istcohnik2 from (
select p1.value->>'raw' as pv1, count(distinct contractor_code)
from stat.phrase p1
  join oems o on o.oem=p1.value->>'raw' 
  join stat.event_request_stat rq on rq.phrase_uid=p1.uid and lower(rq.period) between '9999-99-99' and '9999-99-99' and rq.period_type='M'
where p1.value->>'raw' is not null and contractor_code is not null and src in ('Источник2')
  group by p1.value->>'raw') as T
group by t.pv
```

Сначала пытался объединить через рекурсивные запросы, но это было не то. Наиболее логичным кажется объединение через join и подзапросы.

```
with 
oems as (
select unnest(array['54830D7000']) oem
)
select k.pv, istochnik2, istochnik1 from (
select p.value->>'raw' as pv, count(distinct contractor_code) as istochnik2
from stat.phrase p
  join oems o on o.oem=p.value->>'raw' 
  join stat.event_request_stat rq on rq.phrase_uid=p.uid and lower(rq.period) between '9999-99-99' and '9999-99-99' and rq.period_type='M'
  where p.value->>'raw' is not null and contractor_code is not null and src in ('источник1', 'источник2')
group by p.value->>'raw', contractor_code) as K
  join (select pv, sum(count) as istochnik1 from (
select p1.value->>'raw' as pv1, count(distinct contractor_code)
from stat.phrase p1
  join oems o on o.oem=p1.value->>'raw' 
  join stat.event_request_stat rq on rq.phrase_uid=p1.uid and lower(rq.period) between '9999-99-99' and '9999-99-99' and rq.period_type='M'
where p1.value->>'raw' is not null and contractor_code is not null and src in ('источник1')
  group by p1.value->>'raw', contractor_code) as T on k.pv=t.pv
```

В данном случае, CTE подходит больше, чем where in, так как позволяет повысить производительность и снизить время вычисления.

Comment: В первом запросе в group by оставляете только p.value->>'raw' в списке выборки то же его и например `sum( (src='источник1')::int ) as "источник1"` и аналогично для второго и других источников. конструкцию в sum более классически можно сделать `case when src='источник1' then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: @Mike, не получается. как соединить через join? может у вас есть более изящный вариант?

Comment: А "не получается" это как, что он дает, ошибки какие или данные не те, если проблема с данными, то что именно не так. разворачивание значений из вертикали в горизонталь всегда так делается, как я показал, это самый простой путь. Возможно вы что то недоговариваете и есть какие то нюансы в задаче, или я не так понимаю

Comment: @Mike, Спасибо за уделенное время. Нашел решение самостоятельно. Проблема заключалась  `select t.pv, sum(count) as istcohnik2 from (
select p1.value->>'raw' as pv1, count(distinct contractor_code)
from stat.phrase p1` в этой части кода. Происходила следующая ошибка: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "on"). Пришлось убрать подзапрос и условие `src in ('источник1', 'источник2')`